# How to correct error for sudo apt-get update in xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, xubuntu

When I run `sudo apt-get update` in xubuntu 12.04, it gives:

```
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                                          
Err http://archove.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                                          
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archove.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

The error msg repeats

Err http://archove.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                                                      
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archove.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://archove.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                                                
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archove.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

The program terminates with the msg

Err http://archove.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US                                            
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archove.canonical.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise Release                                                             
E: GPG error: http://packages.medibuntu.org precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Can you help?

Comment: the ubuntu 12.04 expired install a new version

see this https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Comment: 'archove' is spelled 'archive' so you have a typo in your 'sources' file(s), however even that was fixed as Amir said; 12.04LTS is EOL (2012.April + 5 years has passed), 12.04ESM is not supported on this site.  You could change to old-releases.ubuntu.com but you achieve little as no updates go there either.  Upgrade to 14.04LTS (or later) whichare supported.